# Browsing a database as the user is typing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is probably a simple question, but I'm struggling with this.
Basically, how to browse in a database, as the user is typing something?

For example, in a website such as https://www.doesthedogdie.com/, how do they do it to show all the movies beggining with the string of characters you're typing, as you're typing it?
I guess javascript is involved?

Answer (score 2):

[It's called autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Please do some googling next time yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)  or [Bootstrap typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) to achieve this.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference on how to make these kind of systems is fairly awkward, yet it seems to work just fine for me without requiring too much client-side scripting.
I use ASP.NET's Page_Load event to save all content in a SQL database into an XML file. Then, when the user enters some text into the field, I make a hidden div class underneath it unhidden to display filtered results from the XML document. This way, you can update the SQL database at any time fairly simply to add new records which should be listed on the website.
This is server-side scripting, which I prefer to client-side because the user can disable features and mess around with it to view your code which is something I personally hate.
I hope this helps you somewhat.